# Monty Hall multi rounds variation

Tags: probability, game-theory, monty-hall

i was thinking about the Monty Hall problem lately and thought about a different game that is a variation of the original:

There are $100$ doors. behind one of them there's a "$1$", behind all the rest there's a "$0$". you begin the game with $100$ points, each of which awards you at the end of the game $\$1,000$.

You choose a door. the game goes in rounds. each round, the host reduce $1$ point and opens one door with a "$0$" behind it. you then have three options:

1. stay with the door you previously chose.
2. switch a door
3. end the game

once you decide to end the game, you open the last door you chose. if it is a "$1$" you get $\$1,000$ for every point you have remaining ($100$-the amount of rounds it took you to end the game).
if it's a "$0$" you get nothing.
your goal is obviously to get as mouch money as posible.
the hosts goal is for you to get as little points as posible.
my questions for you are:

1. what is the winning strategy (if any) for the player?
2. what is the winning strategy (if any) for the host?
3. will and how will those strategies change if instead of 100 it was N doors and points
4. how will the strategies change if upon opening a door with "$0$" you will get $x$ money instead of nothing?

Comment: There is no strategy for the host if it's required that the host open a door with a zero behind it.

Comment: @quasi  I think there may be.  After the first round, the door you started with has probability $\frac 1{100}$ while the other unopened ones each have probability $\frac {99}{100}\times \frac 1{98}$.  So on the second round the host can choose between a higher probability door and a lower one.

Comment: @quasi  Perhaps it is easy to prove that the host should always open the lowest probability unopened door (or choose uniformly from the lowest probability doors).  That seems likely, after all.

Comment: What happens if there are 2 doors left (you took 98 rounds with 2 points remaining) and you choose the wrong door? Does the host open the door you chose? If so, can the host open the door you chose during earlier rounds if it is the wrong door?

Comment: @lulu: I think the host needs to use a mixed strategy, otherwise, if the host fails to open the lowest probability door, that marks that door as having a 1.

Comment: @quasi  right.  And the weighting isn;t obvious, at least not to me.  Seems like a mess.  After the first few rounds, just keeping track of all the probabilities will be a problem.

Comment: So is the number of points you have the same as the number of doors that are left, or is it one fewer - i.e. if you get to the endgame with two doors left do you have two points or one when you make the final choice. This makes a difference to the "stick to one door till you end and choose" strategy - in the second case your expected outcome seems to me to be constant, in the first case you do better to wait as long as possible before choosing.

Comment: Some observations. The doors you have never chosen will all have the same probability, and absent any special information, this will be higher than the probability on any door you have chosen. Special information might be given by the host's strategy if you are changing doors. If your strategy is to stick to the end and then choose the remaining door, you do best to stick, because then the other door will concentrate $99/100$, and if you ever move you will be sticking on more than $1/100$.

Comment: @Mark Bennet the ammount of points is same as the ammount of doors left, but you cant change your door after you decided to end the game, you stick to the last door you chose. so if you chose door number x and he then open door number Y and you chhose to end the game, you open door number X